# Borrar parte de un objeto en widget Canvas (herramienta "goma de borrar")

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

Estoy tratando de poder borrar libremente parte de los objetos dibujados en el widget canvas haciendo uso del botón borrar,lo que he logrado hacer es dibujar sobre el objeto que en teoría quiero borrar haciendo uso del mismo color que esta de fondo, el problema que al borrar demasiado siento como que se empieza a trancar el programa, y al cambiar de fondo hay un bucle `for` que lo que fue borrado lo cambia al nuevo color de fondo, cuanto mas se borra mas demora en cambiar el fondo.

¿Alguna idea de como borrar de esta forma pero evitando esos problemas?

Adjunto el código aquí abajo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.colorchooser import *

class Paint(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,root = None):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Paint")
        self.root.geometry("+250+10")

        self.opcion = lambda event:None 
        self.size = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.color = None
        self.bgcolor = "white"
        self.create_widgets()


    def create_widgets(self):
        self.Opciones = tk.Frame(self.root,bg="skyblue",width=800,height=60)
        self.Opciones.pack(side=tk.TOP,expand=True,fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.Opciones.pack_propagate(0)

        self.hoja = tk.Canvas(self.root,bg = "white",width = 800,height = 600)
        self.hoja.pack(expand=True,fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.hoja.bind("<B1-Motion>",self.click_action)
        self.hoja.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.reset_line)

        self.Button = ttk.Style()
        self.Button.configure("Button.TButton",selectforeground = "white",fg="black",bg="skyblue",font=("Arial",12),height=1)

        self.Colores = ttk.Button(self.Opciones,style="Button.TButton",text="Colores",width=7,takefocus=0,command = lambda:self.change_action(self.draw))
        self.Colores.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.5,anchor=tk.E)

        self.Fondo = ttk.Button(self.Opciones,style="Button.TButton",text="Fondo",width=7,takefocus=0,command=self.background)
        self.Fondo.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.5,anchor=tk.E)

        self.Scale = ttk.Style()
        self.Scale.configure("Scale.Horizontal.TScale",background="skyblue",troughcolor="red")

        self.Tamaño = ttk.Scale(self.Opciones,style="Scale.Horizontal.TScale",length=300,variable=self.size,value=10,from_=1,to=100)
        self.Tamaño.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.Tamaño.set(15)

        self.Borrar = ttk.Button(self.Opciones,style="Button.TButton",text="Borrar",width=7,takefocus=0,command = lambda:self.change_action(self.delete))
        self.Borrar.place(relx=0.8,rely=0.5,anchor=tk.W)

        self.Limpiar = ttk.Button(self.Opciones,style="Button.TButton",text="Limpiar",width=7,takefocus=0,command=self.clear)
        self.Limpiar.place(relx=0.9,rely=0.5,anchor=tk.W)


    def draw(self,event):           
        if self.x != None and self.y != None:
            try:
                self.hoja.create_line(self.x,self.y,event.x, event.y,width=self.size.get(),capstyle="round",fill=self.color[1])
            except:
                pass

        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y


    def delete(self,event = None):      
        if self.x != None and self.y != None:
            try:
                self.hoja.create_line(self.x,self.y,event.x, event.y,width=self.size.get(),capstyle="round",fill="white",tag="deleted")
            except:
                pass
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def reset_line(self,event = None):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None   


    def changecolor(self):
        self.color = askcolor() 
        if self.color[1] == None:
            self.color = ""
            self.opcion = lambda event:None


    def change_action(self,action = lambda:None):   
        self.opcion = action
        if str(self.opcion) == "<bound method Paint.draw of <__main__.Paint object .!paint>>":
            self.changecolor()


    def click_action(self,event = None):
        self.opcion(event)


    def background(self):       
        self.aux = self.bgcolor     
        self.bgcolor = askcolor()[1]

        if self.bgcolor == None:
            self.bgcolor = self.aux             
        self.hoja.config(bg=self.bgcolor)
        for i in range(len(self.hoja.find_withtag("deleted"))):
            self.hoja.itemconfig(self.hoja.find_withtag("deleted")[i],fill=self.bgcolor)

    def clear(self):
        self.hoja.delete("all")
        self.hoja.config(bg="white")
        self.bgcolor="white"
        self.color=None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App = Paint(root = root)
```

Se tranca al hacer uso de la funcion `background` ya que tiene que recorrer todos los objetos que tienen el tag `"deleted"` y cambiarlos de color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente has diagnosticado el problema perfectamente, el ciclo `for` (especialmente como lo implementas como veremos después) es muy ineficiente y cuantos más items `"delete"` tengas peor será.

Un par de apuntes:

- No uses el operador de igualdad/desigualdad para ver si un objeto es `None` o no. `None` es un singleton, es decir, solo existe una instancia del objeto en un intérprete, por lo que la forma correcta y eficiente de comparar es usar el operador de identidad `is`.

  - `if foo is None` en vez de `if foo == None`.
  - `if foo is not None` en vez de `if foo != None`.

Esto se debe a que toda variable que esté asociada a `None` estará asociada al mismo objeto en memoria ya que solo existe una instancia de `None`. Por lo tanto es más legible y eficiente ver si ambas variables referencian el mismo objeto que no comprobar la igualdad.

- Siempre que solo necesites iterar sobre cualquier iterable, sin reasignar o modificar el tamaño de dicho iterable, usa un ciclo `for in` y no `range + indizado`. Aparte de ser la forma pitónica y más legible de hacerlo es considerablemente más eficiente.

  En vez de:

  ```
  for i in range(len(self.hoja.find_withtag("deleted"))):
      self.hoja.itemconfig(self.hoja.find_withtag("deleted")[i],fill=self.bgcolor)
  ```

  haz simplemente:

  ```
  for item in self.hoja.find_withtag("deleted"):
      self.hoja.itemconfig(item, fill=self.bgcolor)
  ```

  Tu ciclo es altamente ineficiente además por otra razón, en vez de reutilizar la lista retornada por `self.hoja.find_withtag("deleted")`, creas una nueva lista en cada iteración del ciclo llamando de nuevo a `self.hoja.find_withtag("deleted")`  para solo indizar sobre un elemento. En todo caso, deberías hacer:

  ```
  items = self.hoja.find_withtag("deleted")
  for i in range(len(items)):
      self.hoja.itemconfig(items[i], fill=self.bgcolor)
  ```

De todas maneras, la forma más simple y eficiente de hacerlo es simplemente no usar un ciclo.... A `tkinter.canvas.itemconfig` **le puedes pasar como primer argumento una etiqueta directamente y aplicará los cambios a todos los items con esa etiqueta**. Esta es una de las grandes utilidades de las etiquetas en el widget canvas (y en otros casos como `Text`). Es decir:

```
self.hoja.itemconfig("deleted", fill=self.bgcolor)
```

Código completo con algunos cambios para cumplir con PEP-8:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor


class Paint(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Paint")
        self.root.geometry("+250+10")

        self.opcion = lambda event: None
        self.size = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.color = None
        self.bgcolor = "white"
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.opciones = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="skyblue", width=800, height=60)
        self.opciones.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.opciones.pack_propagate(0)

        self.hoja = tk.Canvas(self.root, bg="white", width=800, height=600)
        self.hoja.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.hoja.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.click_action)
        self.hoja.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.reset_line)

        self.button = ttk.Style()
        self.button.configure(
            "button.Tbutton", selectforeground="white", fg="black",
            bg="skyblue", font=("Arial", 12), height=1
            )

        self.colores = ttk.Button(
            self.opciones, style="Button.TButton", text="colores", width=7,
            takefocus=0, command=lambda: self.change_action(self.draw)
            )

        self.colores.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.E)

        self.fondo = ttk.Button(
            self.opciones, style="Button.TButton", text="fondo", width=7,
            takefocus=0, command=self.background
            )
        self.fondo.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.E)

        self.scale = ttk.Style()
        self.scale.configure(
            "scale.Horizontal.TScale", background="skyblue", troughcolor="red"
            )

        self.tamaño = ttk.Scale(
            self.opciones, style="scale.Horizontal.TScale", length=300,
            variable=self.size, value=10, from_=1, to=100
            )
        self.tamaño.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tamaño.set(15)

        self.borrar = ttk.Button(
            self.opciones, style="Button.TButton", text="borrar", width=7,
            takefocus=0, command=lambda: self.change_action(self.delete)
            )
        self.borrar.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.W)

        self.limpiar = ttk.Button(
            self.opciones, style="Button.TButton", text="limpiar", width=7,
            takefocus=0, command=self.clear
            )
        self.limpiar.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.W)

    def draw(self, event):
        if self.x is not None and self.y is not None:
            try:
                self.hoja.create_line(
                    self.x, self.y, event.x, event.y, width=self.size.get(),
                    capstyle="round", fill=self.color[1]
                    )
            except Exception:
                pass
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def delete(self, event=None):
        if self.x is not None and self.y is not None:
            try:
                self.hoja.create_line(
                    self.x, self.y, event.x, event.y, width=self.size.get(),
                    capstyle="round", fill=self.bgcolor, tag="deleted"
                    )
            except Exception:
                pass
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def reset_line(self, event=None):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def changecolor(self):
        self.color = askcolor()
        if self.color[1] is None:
            self.color = ""
            self.opcion = lambda event: None

    def change_action(self, action=lambda: None):
        self.opcion = action
        if self.opcion == self.draw:
            self.changecolor()

    def click_action(self, event=None):
        self.opcion(event)

    def background(self):
        self.aux = self.bgcolor
        self.bgcolor = askcolor()[1]

        if self.bgcolor is None:
            self.bgcolor = self.aux

        self.hoja.config(bg=self.bgcolor)
        self.hoja.itemconfig("deleted", fill=self.bgcolor)

    def clear(self):
        self.hoja.delete("all")
        self.hoja.config(bg="white")
        self.bgcolor = "white"
        self.color = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Paint(root=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]